# Symfony2 form output is different to database value - float with: scale=12, precision=18

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, geolocation, precision

I have a Location Object like this:

```
class Location
{
    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @ORM\Column(name="latitude", type="float", scale=12, precision=18)
     */
    private $latitude;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @ORM\Column(name="longitude", type="float", scale=12, precision=18)
     */
    private $longitude;
```

In my FormType I created the number fields like this:

```
->add('latitude', 'number', array(
    'scale'     => 12
    'precision' => 18,
))
```

I changed in the **php.ini the precision from 12 to 18**!

**

### But I have this problem:

**

I have a value of -65.23305549999998 as longitude in my database and the output in the form is:

[image]

I spend two day on it. I don't know, what to do next. Can somebody help me?

Thanks Michael.

Comment: It should be an output problem, please post the source of the method that outputs this number.

Comment: I have a normal getLongitude() method, very simple with a return $this->longitude; inside. The form field is rendered by symfony2 basic bootstrap template for forms.

Comment: You are saying it " The form field is rendered by symfony2 basic bootstrap template for forms." So the problem must lay somewhere in symfony2. The precision is set to 7 (rounding), so may be you'll find this number some where.

Comment: oh yes, I hope this is not a bug. But thanks for that direction. I think I will look into the data transformer to see, when exactly the float gets rounded.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is if you need this precision, 18 decimals is lower than nano meters, you will find a granule of dust if you have 8 decimals accordingly to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees#Precision

Comment: I tend to agree with @AlexandruOlaru 18 decimals is major overkill.

Comment: ok, that sounds good. I will try it. Thanks ;)